AKS, how to have kubectl label nodes be persistent
I need some node affinity in some deployments (specifically to have DinD, docker in docker, run one per node in my cluster). I need to have multiple DinD but only one of the per nodes.
I add for example: kubectl label nodes aks-nodepool1-16162636-vmss000000 dindId=dind00 and the same for every node in the cluster... Everything works.
Problem is, if the cluster is restarted (for a version upgrade or any other reason) those labels are lost, hence the system won't auto start, as the DinD pods won't deploy as they don't find the node they need to run.
I have also found that AKS assigned new node names when the cluster is restarted. Maybe that's the reason that the label is lost.
Question is: how can I have those node labels persistent or if the cluster is restarted, that the new nodes in the cluster automatically get the corresponding label? (dindId=dind00, dindId=dind01, dindId=dind01...)
